# input field, external keyboard, write at cursor is broken

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input, selection-api

I need to use an external keyboard to populate some input fields.
I need a user to be able to position the cursor to a specific place in the field and the text should continue from that place.

I found a problem with getting a cursor position in the textfield when using selectionStart.

the code below shows the error - instead of adding a digit at the end of textfield, it's added to the beginning as inp.selectionStart returns 0;

Interestingly, I've discovered that if I remove the line inp.focus(); then it's working better when adding digits to the end of the value but when I click on a specific place inside the string, it's working fine once and then braking again and jumps to 0.

```js
let inp;
let btn;
let dig = 0;

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init);

function init() {
  inp = document.getElementById('inp');
  btn = document.getElementById('btn');

  btn.addEventListener("click", add_digit);

  inp.focus();
}

function add_digit() {
  const caretPos = inp.selectionStart;
  console.log('caretPos', caretPos)

  inp.value = inp.value.substring(0, caretPos) + (++dig%10) + inp.value.substring(caretPos);
  
  inp.setSelectionRange(caretPos+1, caretPos+1)
}
```

```html
<input id="inp" />
<button id="btn">add digit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that adding inp.focus() to the end of add_digit() function helped achieve the functionality in the snippet here.

```js
let inp;
let btn;
let dig = 0;

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init);

function init() {
  inp = document.getElementById('inp');
  btn = document.getElementById('btn');

  btn.addEventListener("click", add_digit);

  inp.focus();
}

function add_digit() {
  const caretPos = inp.selectionStart;
  console.log('caretPos', caretPos)

  inp.value = inp.value.substring(0, caretPos) + (++dig%10) + inp.value.substring(caretPos);
  
  inp.setSelectionRange(caretPos+1, caretPos+1);

  inp.focus();
}
```

```html
<input id="inp" />
<button id="btn">add digit</button>
```